# What to render on error in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, render

In my rails application, I've got a partial view with an entry form on it. The form gets included on multiple pages across my app. The form in the partial posts to a RidesController to save with a create method like this:

RidesController.rb

```
def create
  @ride = current_user.rides.build(params[:ride])
  if @ride.save
    flash[:success] = "Ride created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    @rides = current_user.rides.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'pages/home'   # <---- WHAT GOES HERE?
  end
end
```

I've commented the line where my question is. When we have an error, I need to present the same view that the user is presently on. But because this controller is being invoked from a partial instead of a full view, I don't know how to tell what context it's coming from.

Right now if there's an error on /rides/new, the user ends up redirected to the homepage which also has the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is pass the template path in with the form.

Add this to each main view that includes the form partial (e.g. pages/home, rides/new, etc):

```
<% @current_page_template = __FILE__ %>
```

In your form partial:

```
<%= form_for ... do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'current_page_template',
      @current_page_template.sub(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'views'), '') %>
```

In your controller:

```
def create
  ...
  if @ride.save
    ...
  else
    ...
    render params[:current_page_template]
  end
end
```

Comment: That worked for me. Only change was that String::sub needs a second argument, but I couldn't edit the answer as it was only a two character change.